# ASP ObjectDataSource binding even though DataBind() not called

Tags: asp.net, webforms, objectdatasource

I've recently run into an issue with my ASP ObjectDataSource using a GridView.

My code.....

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" EnablePaging="True" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectCountMethod="GetRowCount" SelectMethod="CriteriaSearch" TypeName="AssemblyNameRemoved">
        <SelectParameters>              
          <asp:SessionParameter Name="criteria" SessionField="OrderCriteria" Type="Object" />                
            <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Name="rowCount" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" CellPadding="0" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
  //code removed for brevity
</asp:GridView>
```

Now, this code hasn't changed for quite some time.  But we recently updated to .Net 4.8.  And since then, before the Page_Load event even fires (where I will load up my criteria object and then DataBind the grid) the function CriteriaSearch is getting called, and then my Page_Load event fires and I end up calling DataBind() and the function will run again.

Edit: Code-behind has not changed in years either, and testing on old .Net framework this is not an issue.

I did some research on .Net framework 4.8 update, but nothing stuck out as to why this would have changed.

Any help/references would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but couldn't. Still needed to call DataBind() in 4.8 for an SqlDataSource or other binding to work.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  Will need to investigate some of the other, non-related, changes that were made to see if something else if affecting my issue.

Comment: The Base Class had some new code that would loop through all controls on the page looking for a specific MessageBox type, and apparently this code was causing a premature binding on the GridView merely from accessing the control in the loop and checking it's TypeOf.